# number of integers limit proof

Tags: calculus, limits

find the limit of the number of integers $k$ satisfying $n{\sqrt{2}}{\leq}k{\leq}n(1+{\sqrt{2}})$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

How can I obtrain a formula for the no. of integers

Comment: Note that you need not always produce an explicit formula for a quantity to determine a limit of that quantity.

Comment: I think the question you should ask yourself is, are there any integers that have the property that after a certain point $N$, for all $n \geq N$, the integer is between $n\sqrt{2}$ and $n(1 + \sqrt{2})$?  If there are integers that satisfy this property, then the number of integers that satisfy this property is your answer.

Comment: @user46944: The limit of each side of the equality is $\infty$. How does this help?

Comment: @user46944 Ah, I read this differently, namely as computing the limit of the sequence of the numbers $a_n$ of integers $k$ that satisfy the condition for the respective integers $n$.

Comment: @Travis I think your interpretation makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an odd question. Let's start from the fact that the number of integers $k$ satisfying $n\sqrt{2}\leq k \leq n(1+{\sqrt{2}})$ is exactly $n$, if $n$ is a strictly positive integer.

First you ask:

> find the limit of the number of integers k satisfying $n\sqrt{2}\leq k \leq n(1+{\sqrt{2}})$ as n tends to infinity.

Well, the limit of $n$ as $n$ tends to infinity is infinity. But then you ask:

> How can I obtrain a formula for the no. of integers

This is a different question! And the formula is simply $n$.

But it's not clear what you really wanted to ask.

Comment: I have now posted the original question which prompted this one. Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929823/proving-a-tricky-limit-is-zero

Answer (score 1):

The set
$$\{k\in{\Bbb R}\mid n\sqrt2\le k\le n(1+\sqrt2)\}$$
is an interval of length $n$ on the real line, and its endpoints are not integers, so it contains exactly $n$ integer values of $k$.

Comment: I have now posted the original question which prompted this one. Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929823/proving-a-tricky-limit-is-zero

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1(x) = x \sqrt 2, \quad f_2(x)=x(1+\sqrt 2)$.

The number of integers k that satisfy $n \sqrt 2 \le k \le n(1+\sqrt 2)$ is at most $\lceil f_2(n) - f_1nx) \rceil$.

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}[f_2(x)-f_1(x)] = \lim_{x \to \infty}(x+x \sqrt 2 - x \sqrt 2)=\lim_{x \to \infty}x = \infty
$$

So as $n \to \infty$ an infinite number of integers $k$ satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You have $k(n)=\lfloor n(1+\sqrt 2) \rfloor - \lfloor n\sqrt 2 \rfloor \gt (n(1+\sqrt 2)-1)-(n\sqrt 2)=n-1$ so for given $n$ there are at least $n-1$ integers in the interval, which shows   $k(n) \to \infty$

Comment: I have now posted the original question which prompted this one. Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929823/proving-a-tricky-limit-is-zero