# proving a tricky limit is zero

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $$S=\{x+{\sqrt{2}}:0\leq x\leq 1\}$$ and $$A_{n}=\{0,1/n,2/n,...\}$$

Let $C_{n}=|S{\cap}A_{n}|$. Prove that the $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{C_{n}}{n}=0$$.

My attempt: $x+{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{k}{n}$ implies $x=\frac{k-{\sqrt{2}}n}{n}$. We need $x$ to be between 0 and 1 so the cardinality is the number of integers $k$ satisfying $n{\sqrt{2}}{\leq}k{\leq}n(1+{\sqrt{2}})$.

But this means the cardinality is $n$ which won't make the limit zero. Thanks for any help

Comment: The limit is $1$, not $0$.

Comment: @TonyK look at page 7 here http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf.

Comment: Your formulation of the problem is different: in the link, $S = \{ x + \sqrt{2} : x \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q} \}$. This is a rather different object from $\{ x + \sqrt{2} : x \in [0,1] \}$. In the latter case you will get $1$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks; can you show me how to get 1?

Comment: Your OP is one step away from getting the limit to be 1....

Comment: @Ian sorry I meant 0

Comment: @Ian the first formulation is what I wanted

Comment: @GregMartin sorry I mean the first formulation and get the limit to be zero

Comment: @Ian So the cardinality is the no. of integers k satisfying 0<(k/n)+sqrt(2)<1. But where do I go from here?

Comment: @Ian I think I get it now. The intersection is the empty set since a rational + irrational is an irrational. Correct?

Comment: You're asking all these questions about more or less the same thing, but none of them quite makes sense. What do you _really_ want to know?

Answer (score 0):

The set $S=[\sqrt{2}, 1+\sqrt{2}]$ as OP points out we need the number of $k$ such that 
$$n{\sqrt{2}}{\leq}k{\leq}n(1+{\sqrt{2}})
$$ and this is either $n$ or $n-1$. Since both $\frac{n}{n}$ and $\frac{n-1}{n}$ limit to $1$ we have that the correct limit is $1$.

Comment: sorry I mistated the question. I have answered it in the comments. I have another question: Can you think of a set $S$ where the limit does not exist? Thanks